# Convertted tensorflow model to tflite outputs a int8 which I cannot dequantize

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I currently have quantized a tensorflow model using the following class script:

```
class QuantModel():

def __init__(self, model=tf.keras.Model,data=[]):
    '''
    1. Accepts a keras model, long term will allow saved model and other formats
    2. Accepts a numpy or tensor data of the format such that indexing such as
    data[0] will return one input in the correct format to be fed forward through the
    network
    '''
    self.data=data
    self.model=model


'''Added script to quantize model and allows custom ops
for Logmelspectrogram operations (Might cause mix quantization)'''
def quant_model_int8(self):
    converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(self.model)
    converter.representative_dataset=self.representative_data_gen
    converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
    converter.inference_input_type = tf.int8  # or tf.uint8
    converter.inference_output_type = tf.int8  # or tf.uint8
    #converter.allow_custom_ops=True
    converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
    tflite_model_quant = converter.convert()
    open("converted_model2.tflite",'wb').write(tflite_model_quant)
    return tflite_model_quant




'''Returns a tflite model with no quantization i.e. weights and variable data all
in float32'''
def convert_tflite_no_quant(self):
    converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(self.model)
    tflite_model = converter.convert()
    open("converted_model.tflite",'wb').write(tflite_model)
    return tflite_model


def representative_data_gen(self):
    # Model has only one input so each data point has one element.
    yield [self.data]
```

I am able to successfully quantize my model, however the input & output is int8 as those are the options once you quantize.

Now to run the modle I am using the tf.quantization.quantize to change my input data to a qint data format and feed it through my network. So as expected I get an output which is int8.

I want to conveert the output back to float32 and inspect it. For that i am using tf.dequantize. However that only works with tf.qint8 data types.

Wondering how to handle this and if any of you have run into similar issue?

```
# Load the TFLite model and allocate tensors.
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="converted_model2.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
data_arr= np.load('Data_Mel.npy')
print(data_arr.shape)
sample=data_arr[0]
print(sample.shape)
minn=min(sample.flatten())
maxx=max(sample.flatten())
print(minn,maxx)

(sample,sample_1,sample_2)=tf.quantization.quantize(data_arr[0],minn,maxx,tf.qint8)
print(sample.shape)
    
# Test the model on random input data.
input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']
input_data = sample
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)


interpreter.invoke()

# The function `get_tensor()` returns a copy of the tensor data.
# Use `tensor()` in order to get a pointer to the tensor.
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
print(output_data.dtype)
output_data=tf.quantization.dequantize(output_data,minn,maxx)
print(output_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply remove the `converter.inference_input_type = tf.int8` and `converter.inference_output_type = tf.int8` flags and treat the output model as a float model. Here is some detail:

The "optimization" flag in the Converter quantizes the float model to int8. By default, it adds a [Quant] op in the beginning of the quantized model as well as a [Dequant] at the end:

(float) ->[Quant] -> (int8) -> [op1] -> (int8) -> [op...] -> (int8) -> [Dequant] -> (float)

So you don't need to change any of your driver logic since the overall model still has float interface while the [op]s are quantized.

The extra flag `converter.inference_input_type = tf.int8` and `converter.inference_output_type = tf.int8` allows you to remove the [Quant] and [Dequant] operation so the quantized model looks like this:

(int8) -> [op1] -> (int8) -> [op...] -> (int8)

This is for deployment on certain hardware/workflow. Since you are adding [Quant] and [Dequant] manually, the quantized model with float interface could work better for your case.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the info. I am aware of that and the purpose of quantization is to deploy on hardware. But before I do that I want to evaluate performance of the model on a test data and for that I am doing the above mentioned i.e. predicting the model as an int8 which is how I will deploy it.

Comment: I see. If you really want to test the int8 model, you can use simple python code to do the conversion between float and int8 instead of using the heavy weight TF op.